# Can't open Vertex AI notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm experiencing some weird issues with my ai-notebook (and haven't found any materials on how to fix the issues). Basically what happens is:
sometimes when I'm in the Vertex AI console and click "Open Jupyterlab" nothing happens for a while and then I get an error message saying "Unable to start notebook"

If I insist and click again, I get a pop up where jupyter finally looks like it'll load, but the page is always blank

I tried restarting my notebook a few times already but nothing seems to work :confused: has anyone ever had a similar issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Did you find a solution?